# Groovy - Closures - No signature of method: FeedClass.feedData() is applicable for argument types: (Data, FeedClass$_closure1)

Tags: groovy, closures

I am trying to understand how the closures really work in Groovy and how to pass these closures in a method.

I have the FeedClass and the feedData method and inside this method I have defined a closure.

However, even if the closure is defined internally in the method, I keep receiving the error No Signature of method... It seems as if it is expecting the closure in the method arguments.

```
 void feedData(def Data) {

            def calculateData=
                    {
                        if (it.even== null || it.odd== null)
                            println "error"
                        else
                                      println "Ok"
                    }

            Data.numbers.each calculateData
 }
```

This is the class and how I invoke the method

FeedClass(def Data) {

```
feedData(Data) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `feedData` method is currently not expecting a second argument, it should be declared like this:

```
void feedData(def Data, def calculator) {
    Data.numbers.each(calculateData)
}
```

And it can be called like this:

```
feedData(Data) { data ->
    if (data.even == null || data.odd == null)
        println "error"
    else
        println "Ok"
}
```